# How to filter data based on the scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I have the following simplified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNGTfLMJcwzn9NDYheel?p=preview) to demonstrate my issue:

html:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:{show:true}" data-question="question">    </my-directive>
```

directive:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.questions = [
    {qid:'1', show: true, text:'what is?'},
    {qid:'2', show: false, text:'who is?'},
    {qid:'3', show: true, text:'where is?'}
 ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
  link: function(scope){
    scope.getShow = function(){
      // some logic to determine show
      // for simlicity , always return true so all questiosn show
      return true;
    };
  },
  restrict: "E",
  scope: {
    question: "="
  },
  template: '<h1>{{question.text}}</h1>'
  };
});
```

Currently, the filter works based on the 'show' value that comes from the raw data model. but i am trying to clean it from raw data and make it work based on the `getShow()` logic that is defined at the question's scope level.

Generally, I cannot figure out a way to filter based on fields or functions on the scope, rather than on the data model, and could not find an example of how this could be done.

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and only use demo sites as support for what is actually in the question

Comment: Really not clear what you are wanting to do either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `ng-repeat` just set an `ng-show` equal to the `getShow()` function and pass along the iterated question.

Get `getShow()` to check if show is true or false, and return that value.

`app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.questions = [
    {qid:'1', show: true, text:'what is?'},
    {qid:'2', show: false, text:'who is?'},
    {qid:'3', show: true, text:'where is?'}
  ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope){
      scope.getShow = function(question){
        // some logic to determine show
        // for simlicity , always return true so all questiosn show
        return question.show
      };
    },
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      question: "="
    },
    template: '<h1>{{question.text}}</h1>'
  };
});
```

and `index.html`

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show="getShow(question)" data-question="question">
```

And of course, [the editable plunker to show.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYbCARtbK8U1Ej4OG9Ui)

Comment: super simple. i probably over-complicated it. thank you.